# Jquery - Button not enabled when selecting checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two buttons disabled by default and I want them to be enabled after atleast one checkbox is clicked. But for some reason I am not sure why the buttons are not being enabled. I followed what a few similar StackOverflow questions suggested. This is what i have:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']")
    checkboxes.click(function() {
        $('#seen').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
        $('#delete').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});

user = $(location).attr('href').split('/').slice(-1)[0];
$.ajax({
url: '/userdata/' + user,
type: 'GET',
success: function (response) {
    var trHTML = '';
    var is_user = response.is_user;
    if (is_user === true) {
    $.each(response.links, function (i, item) {
        trHTML += '<tr><td style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" value='+item.id+' name="link"/></td>' + 
                  '<td class="col-md-8"><a href="'+item.url+'">'+item.name+'</a></td><td style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-2">'+item.date+'</td></tr>';
    });
    $('.todolist').append(trHTML);
    }
    else {
        $.each(response.links, function (i, item) {
        trHTML += '<tr>' + 
                  '<td class="col-md-8"><a href="'+item.url+'">'+item.name+'</a></td><td style="text-align:center;" class="col-md-2">'+item.date+'</td></tr>';
    });
         $('.todolist').append(trHTML);
    }
}
});

});


function onClickSeen() {
/* declare an checkbox array */
var chkArray = [];

/* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
$( 'input[name="link"]:checked' ).each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
});

/* we join the array separated by the comma */
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join(',');

//alert("You have selected " + selected)

$.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "/set-seen",
            data: { 'selected': selected },
            success:function(result){
                location.reload(true);
        }});
}

function onClickDelete() {
/* declare an checkbox array */
var chkArray = [];

/* look for all checkboes that have a class 'chk' attached to it and check if it was checked */
$( 'input[name="link"]:checked' ).each(function() {
    chkArray.push($(this).val());
});

/* we join the array separated by the comma */
var selected;
selected = chkArray.join(',');

//alert("You have selected " + selected)

$.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "/delete-links",
            data: { 'selected': selected },
            success:function(result){
                location.reload(true);
        }});
}
```

This is what the HTML of the two buttons look like:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="onClickSeen()" id="seen" disabled>Mark as Seen</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="onClickDelete()" id="delete" disabled>Delete</button>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered todolist">

</table>
```

I would really appreciate some help here. I even tried replacing the click with the on method.

Comment: ..and where are your checkboxes in your HTML?

Comment: if you look at the javascript code, i generate them after getting a response from an AJAX GET request

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/rigubi/2/edit?html,js,output

You need to delegate your click cause you dymanically generate your checkboxes

use the `.on()` method like

```
$("body"/*use rather a static parent ID here*/).on("click", "[name=someCkbName]", function() {

  var checkboxes = $("[name=someCkbName]"); // get all
  $('#seen, #delete').prop('disabled', !checkboxes.is(":checked"));

});
```

The `.on()` story goes like this: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("staticSelector").on("eventName", "dynamicChildSelector", callbackFn);
```

Comment: i have a couple of questions. 1) why do it on the body tag? 2) how can we restrict the click event on checkboxes with a given name?

Comment: also your suggestion did not work. maybe the attribute name (':checkbox') is incorrect?

Comment: @ueg1990 you don't have to use a `"body"` but rather a `"#staticParent"`

Comment: @ueg1990 added a demo

Comment: your latest suggestion worked...i replaced 'body' with outermost div id that contained the buttons and table....thank you very much :)

Comment: @ueg1990 you're welcome! Sorry for the constant fixes. Took me some time to get your requirements.

Comment: why do we have to delegate click due to the dynamic generation? also i dynamically generate the table...not the checkboxes

Comment: @ueg1990 table or checkboxes, no difference, the checkboxes do not exist at the time you're preparing your click function. Therefore you need to delegate the click listener to an existing parent element using: `$("staticSelector").on("eventName", "dynamicChildSelector", callbackFn);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106515/discussion-between-ueg1990-and-roko-c-buljan).